# I just got my domain vsmathur.co.in verified by Google Domains, but cannot access my WordPress site, Help!

Tags: troubleshooting, google-chrome

Folks,

Just to give you a brief history, I have been running my WordPress site located at:

http://vsmathur.co.in successfully till 10th of December, 2019. I was also able to access the `/wp-admin`.

Then I registered my domain with `domains.google.com`, and suddenly my website stops responding, giving me a 404 Error (See Screenshot below)
[image: Error-Msg-404-vsmathur.co.in]

I tried changing the `A` Record on my site to know avali. I even created a new `.htaccess` file with the Re-Write rule, but it still does not work, please help, I am at my wit's end here!!

Comment: This most likely is something you should sort out with your hosting provider. It has nothing to do with WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've transferred your Domain in to Google as you are getting the Google 404 page?
It looks like you still need to point the domain to your webserver by changing the nameservers.